# Library function for sorting based on a predicate

Tags: collections, clojure

Does a function exist in the Clojure library for filtering a collection, and returning a pair of collections, one of which contains the items where the predicate returned true, and the other which contains the items where the predicate returned false?

For example:

```
(let [[yays nays] (some-fn pred coll)] ... )
```

More or less, I am looking for a way to sort based on the predicate, rather than throw away (like with `filter` or `remove`).

(Note: I know that a solution is to call `filter` and `remove` on the collection separately;  I just would like to know if there is a builtin function that can accomplish this more efficiently).

(Edit:  `seq-utils/separate` doesn't qualify as more efficient.  It evaluates the predicate twice for each item.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`clojure.core/group-by`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/group-by)

Answer (score 1):

If you want maximum performance you'll want to do this using loop/recur, something like:

```
(defn separate-by [pred coll]
     (loop [yays nil 
            nays nil 
            s (seq coll)]
       (if s
         (let [item (first s)
               test (pred item)]
           (if test
             (recur (conj yays item) nays (next s))
             (recur yays (conj nays item) (next s))))
         {:yays yays :nays nays})))
```

The reason this is most efficient is that the loop/recur enables you to iteratively build the two output lists without any extra memory allocations (which would happen if you repeated updated a map for example) or reference overhead (which would happen if you used two atoms to accumulate the results).

Comment: This reverses the order of the input sequence, which is usually an unexpected side effect. Probably better to start with `[]` rather than `nil`. But this is surely the fastest way to do it: I don't see any inefficiencies at all. Note, though, @scrapdog, that this solution is not lazy (nor is mine). Any solution which is both lazy and immutable will necessarily walk over the sequence twice.